# Warning: Identity file InstanceLaunch.pem not accessible: No such file or directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, vnc-viewer

I know this question has been asked on here before, however, the solutions on previous posts don't seem to be working for me. I am trying to use this command in the console "ssh -L 5901:localhost:5901 -i InstanceLaunch.pem ubuntu@ec2-3-86-18-37.compute-1.amazonaws.com". The error I get back is what is stated in the title. It says there is no file or directory. The file path to my "InstanceLaunch.pem" file is the following:

```
C:\uniyear4\aws-account
```

People have suggested stating the path of the .pem file however when I do that, the same error message is displayed. I am trying to set this up to connect the the localhost through my VNC viewer. The connection is being set up using AWS.

I don't know if this will have anything to do with it but in my text document (instructions) that I must follow, I have to add the following and "append them to the startup file":

```
gnome-panel &
gnome-settings-daemon &
metacity &
nautilus &
```

This is what I have currently inputted:

```
#!/bin/sh

xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
#x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
#x-window-manager &
# Fix to make GNOME work
export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
/etc/X11/Xsession
gnome-panel &
gnome-settings-daemon &
metacity &
nautilus &
```

It says at the bottom to append I must use M-A. I believe the M is alt and the A is just the letter A. When I click these at the same time nothing happens. Am I doing something wrong?

Any help would be much appreciated.